# gwt - dart - polymer integration

Tags: gwt, dart, polymer, dart-polymer

i have a developed gwt application and have it in production.

i  would like to continue development in dart as developing/debugging 
seems way better to me than with gwt.

i already have written some modules in pure dart and am able to integrate the compiled js in the gwt app. communication between gwt<->dart via json also works fine.

now i would like to integrate some dart/polymer elements but did not have any success doing it. 
is anybody doing this? is it possible? any hints?

this is my gwt host page. how do i get polymer imported/initialised/started?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.nocache.js"></script>

  </head>

  <!--                                           -->
  <!-- The body can have arbitrary html, or      -->
  <!-- you can leave the body empty if you want  -->
  <!-- to create a completely dynamic UI.        -->
  <!--                                           -->
  <body>
    <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>

    <!-- RECOMMENDED if your web app will not function without JavaScript enabled -->
    <noscript>
      <div id="cwm" style="width: 22em; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -11em; color: red; background-color: white; border: 1px solid red; padding: 4px; font-family: sans-serif">
    Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled
    in order for this application to display correctly.
      </div>
    </noscript>

    <!-- DART integration-->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="dart_application/web/dart_plain.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
    <script src="dart_application/web/packages/browser/dart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's your problem?! Any errors? Show us your code.

Comment: already found the solution. instead of including polymer into gwt, I use the html file produced by the polymer transformer as entry point and  include the gwt javascript int this page.

Comment: Then please post your solution and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

my original setup as posted was to include the dart main file into the entry point html file of the gwt project.

```
script src="dart_application/web/dart_plain.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
```

in this setup i copied the outpout from pub build into a subdirectory of the gwt web app tree (dart_applikation)

this worked fine for plain dart.

what I do now is:

1) make the entry point html file of the dart/polymer app the entry point file for the gwt
app. (this is done by a script copying the dart2js/pub build output to the gwt tree)

2) include the gwt js file in the main html file of the dart polymer project at the very beginning of the file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.nocache.js"></script>
```

3) include also all the additional js files gwt needs in the main dart html file.

following are the steps top produce a app.war file that includes my gwt and dart-polymer app:

a) pub build the dart-polymer project

b) compile the gwt project

c) copy the "build/web" directory to the root of the webapps directory of the gwt project.

d) zip all together to one war file.

a bit hacky, but it seems to work.